# avoid instantiating maven dependency plugin

Tags: maven-2

I would like to use the "deploy"-phase of maven to deploy some files to my appliance (using a custom maven plugin), but I don't need the maven-deploy-plugin.

There are several answers on stackoverflow and the rest of the web on how to avoid a plugin being run, for example:

- [maven exclude plugin defined in parent pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839581/maven-exclude-plugin-defined-in-parent-pom)
- [Disable a Maven plugin defined in a parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom)

I have tried setting `<phase>none`, `<skip>true` and `<inherited>false`.  However, the plugin is still configured, which fails with message:

> failed to configure plugin parameters for org.apache.maven.plugins maven-deploy-plugin 2.4

because there is no distributionManagement-element in my pom.

Is there a way to completely remove the dependency-plugin from the maven lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is unlikely to work even with those workarounds simply because the `maven-deploy-plugin` is a core plugin, like it or not.

Therefore, here's another hack:

- Create a profile.
- Define your plugin in it and attach it to the `install` phase.
- Trigger the deployment, by invoking your profile.

Not as fancy as you would have hoped for, but it should do the trick. If anyone has better ideas, I would also like to hear them, as I've faced this sort of issue as well.

Comment: I didn't create a profile, but I attached my plugin to the install-phase instead of deploy, and I disabled install with skip=true.