# SpringBoot: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine.Technologies used:
Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have an SpringBoot app. with these 2 classes:

```
@Profile("!war")
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({SecurityConfig.class ,PersistenceConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class})
public class BookApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Profile("war")
@Import({SecurityConfig.class ,PersistenceConfig.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookApplicationWar extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BookApplicationWar.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BookApplicationWar.class, args);
    }

}
```

I generate the war with this command

```
 mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dspring.profiles.active=pebloc,war -DAPP-KEY=pebloc
```

But I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project book: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.tdk.BookApplication, com.tdk.BookApplicationWar] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: This happens because you may have 2 main methods

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you have more than one main class, you need to explicitly [configure the main class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#mainClass) in each profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <properties>
          <spring.boot.mainclass>com.SomeClass</spring.boot.mainclass>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <properties>
          <spring.boot.mainclass>com.SomeOtherClass</spring.boot.mainclass>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    ...
</plugin>
```

See [**spring-boot:repackage**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)

Comment: and the tag @Profile I use is useless ?

Comment: Maven profiles and Spring profiles are two different concepts.

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada I know, but Maven is causing the trouble, so you will have to solve it there

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada the problem is not Spring, but the Jar itself. A Jar manifest can only have one main class defined. Spring Profiles only get activated inside the main class.

Comment: Still same error, this solution does not work

Comment: I'm trying the described approach and it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76807834/283837  Perhaps someone could tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 59):

Define single main class via start-class property

```
<properties>
      <start-class>com.may.Application</start-class>
</properties>
```

Alternatively, define the main class in the spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.may.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Or via profiles

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.may.Application1</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile2</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.may.Application2</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: One property! Great solution!

Comment: Adding the mainClass tag to configuration had no effect, but setting the property did.

Comment: @user515655 here is the official doc for spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration and it still says that mainClass tag should work https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging. don't know why it didn't work for you.

Comment: The 2nd solution (mainClass) totally works!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 20):

To disambiguate the entry point of a spring boot application, you can add the following directive to your Gradle build file

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'your.org.bla.TestKt'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Seems this has changed to `mainClass` only.

See the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.configuring.main-class

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes this error is given when you do mvn install without doing mvn clean.

Comment: Diddo for Gradle.  This may happen when changing the package name when the project was already build once.  In that case the clean does wonders.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Package refactoring was done, but didn't clean it.

Answer (score 12):

or simply hard code the main class in plugin configuration.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>your.main.class.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This doesn't work at least for me i think <confguration> must be at the same level as <groupId> and <artifactId>. @EugeneMaysyuk answer is the most concise and complete so far

Answer (score 10):

From the command line you can use

```
... -Dstart-class=com.your.package.application.BookApplication
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Where did you find this ?

Answer (score 5):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project book: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.tdk.BookApplication, com.tdk.BookApplicationWar]
```

One possible reason to getting following error is  more than one main methods in your code, Spring boot allow only one main method across all class in same project.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Spring Boot Application generally there is only one main class that has `@SpringBootApplication` , If you add another `main` method in the application some where , the gradle build process gets confused . So add the following at the root level of your `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'packageNameAfter.srcMainJavaFolder.YourClassName'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.main.class.MainClass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Element *configuration* must be inside the *plugin* one!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I had renamed my Application class containing main from foo.java to bar.java, cleaned and updated. So I only ever had one main.

The error went away when I deleted the old generated class, foo.class under the target folder.

Comment: A similar solution worked for me -- I'm using Grails on a Mac, so just `./gradlew clean` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application if you have multiple classes with `public static void main(String[] args)`. Remove the one that you do not need. Specially if you generate the project with  `https://start.spring.io/` it comes with a class with main method in it.

If you do need all of the classes with main method just explicitly mention which one would to be boos-trapped up on application start up by mentioning it in the pom.

Answer (score 0):

I was building a spring boot library project, so I don't need a main starter class, 
so I faced the same issue while building the project with maven, so I removed the maven plugin to compile successfully

```
<!--
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
-->
```

For a more detailed example. find it here
https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use profiles to avoid the error. You can configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version> <!-- use the corresponding version of your spring boot -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>repackage-application1</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.yourpackage1.Application1</mainClass>
                    <finalName>app1</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>target/apps</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>repackage-application2</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.yourpackage2.Application2</mainClass>
                    <finalName>app2</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>target/apps</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

This will create app1.jar and app2.jar in your target folder.

**Important note**: if you inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent, it executes by default the spring-boot-maven-plugin with a default configuration that expects only one spring application. If you have two apps in a module, that default configuration will fail with the error "Unable to find a single main class" error. To fix your build you need to deactivate the default plugin execution in your parent pom. One way to do it could be to exclude a plugin in the parent pom you can take a look at [maven exclude plugin defined in parent pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839581/maven-exclude-plugin-defined-in-parent-pom) (did not try it myself)

Answer (score 0):

I defined two `@SpringBootApplication` on purpose. To avoid conflicts in Gradle I defined additional tasks with alternative `mainClass`:

```
tasks.named("bootRun", BootRun.class).configure {
    mainClass = "com.evil.App"
}
tasks.named("bootJar", BootJar.class).configure {
    mainClass = "com.evil.App"
}

tasks.register("bootRunH2", BootRun.class) {
    group = bootRun.group
    description = bootJar.description
    mainClass = "com.evil.H2App"
}
tasks.register("bootJarH2", BootJar.class) {
    group = bootJar.group
    description = bootJar.description
    targetJavaVersion = bootJar.targetJavaVersion
    classpath = bootJar.classpath
    mainClass = "com.evil.H2App"
}
```

This way you can have as many different `bootRun`/`bootJar` tasks as you wish.