# Maven build Failure ( Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [Application, pfc.app.Application] )

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I was working in my project, everything was fine, then when I try to rebuild with mvn repack -e, it does a build failure, this is the error :

[Build failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F12Tu.png)

This is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pfc.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Realy need some help guys ..

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840576/springboot-unable-to-find-a-single-main-class-from-the-following-candidates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840576/springboot-unable-to-find-a-single-main-class-from-the-following-candidates)

Comment: It's not a duplicate the  error is the same but the cause is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what the problem was, I just deleted the target directory, and rerun the packaging, it worked  ! thanks for the help.